# create ssl and enable in httpd

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, ssl

I would like to create an ssl certificate on my centos server and add support for it in
my httpd.conf.
I'm not sure how to do it

Answer (score 1):

The following link will help you to create SSL certificates and also it will help to configure the same in httpd.conf.

http://techtrunch.com/linux/generating-installing-ssl-certificate